# Hi there ask a short sale question

Tags: finance

I know the proceeds (5175)and initial margin deposit (3105)
But I don't know the total deposit with the broker
Why it is 5175+3105
I was confused that the proceeds include the initial margin deposit, so why it is added twice?
Thanks for answering!

[image]